# Time stability of features in XGBoost (in a GLM sense)

Tags: xgboost, glm

I have a lot of experience in building data-driven models from a GLM perspective (stuff like conversion models for consumer buying certain goods).

Often times the datasets I used came from several years and hence one of the potential features was "YearOfBusiness". When building a model I always paid attention that individual GLM features showed the same trends over the different YOB as I then could assume that these feature are really showing non-random behavior. Say the effect of male vs. female was always such that feat(m) < feat(f) in any year of the data. If the effect was not showing the same direction in different years I would not include it in the GLM.

Currently, I am playing around with XGboost to better understand what it is capable of and how I might benefit from it.

My question is:
Consistency over time has always been a very important test on whether to include a feature in a GLM or not. How would I test "consistency over time" in a setting using XGBoost as my prediction algorithm?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to test will be to assign one block of time data one label and another one another label; followed by fitting a xgboost model over it.

So if you have data from 2018 and 2019; then give all 2018 data label 0 and 2019 data label 1 and build a classification model using xgboost. Build shallow tree and note top feature. Remove this top feature and repeat. All variables which shows some discriminative power should be thus checked for time consistency.